# Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds during Selenium WebDriver with C# testing using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013

I'm new to Selenium Testing and trying to learn it.

When running the test, I have an error `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:`
Failed to start up socket within 45000 milliseconds`

This is my sample code:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTest
{
    IWebDriver driver;
    [TestMethod]
    public void VerifyTitle()
    {
        //Write Actual Test
        string title = driver.Title;
        Assert.AreEqual(title, "Done The deal");
    }
[TestInitialize]
public void Setup()
{
    //start browser and oprn url
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://Donethedeal.com/");
}

[TestCleanup]
public void CleanupTest()
{
    //close browser
    driver.Quit();
}
```

}

I installed, I think, all necessary libraries using NuGet Package Manager
I have installed `Selenium.WebDriver -Version 2.53.1` instead of 3.0.0 beta, since only with this version I was able to start Firefox browser. However, I could not open the url and got the described error while doing so

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

at first your mistake is in the `IWebDriver` object declaration. You are declaring the object locally in the `SetUp()` method. If you do that the range of the object is inside the method only. Outside of the method the object is null. So move the declaration outside of all methods (preferably on the top, such as bellow)
The next mistake is the Attributes that you are using. I have to mention here that I used the `NUnit3TestAdapter` and `NUnit` from `Nuget`. I didnt find nowhere your attributes so I add mine :) 
In the SetUp method I used the [SetUp] attribute
 in the `CleanUp[TearDown]`
 and in `VerifyTitle` [Test].
 Take a look in the code bellow for more details

```
 IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public void VerifyTitle()
    {
        //Write Actual Test
        string title = driver.Title;
        // Assert.AreEqual(title, "DoneThedeal");
        ////I wanted to keep it simple change it back if u wish
        if (title.Contains("DoneTheDeal"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(title);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Title not found");
        }

    }
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        //start browser and oprn url

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://Donethedeal.com/");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void CleanupTest()
    {
        //close browser
        driver.Quit();
    }
}
```

**If you want to see the console results look for "Output" in the Text Explorer